# Understanding the Eisenstein's lemma proof on Wikipedia.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

> $1.$ Why is it that in the proof of Eisenstein's lemma (the addendum on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity#Proof_of_Eisenstein%27s_lemma)), $$(-1)^{(p-1)/2} \equiv (-1)^{\sum_{\ u} \lfloor qu/p\rfloor} \equiv (-1)^{\sum_{\ u} r(u)+u},$$ where $1\leq u\leq (p-1)/2$?

> $2.$ Also, why does the lemma follow easily from Gauss' lemma?

I know that if $u$ is an integer, then $\lfloor qu/p\rfloor \equiv r(u) + u\mod 2$. The first question thus amounts to proving that $$\displaystyle\sum_{1\leq u\leq (p-1)/2}\left\lfloor\frac{qu}p\right\rfloor\equiv (p-1)/2 \mod 2.$$ Gauss' Lemma says that $$\left(\frac{q}p\right) = (-1)^{|qP\ \cap\ N|},$$ where $P$ is the set of residues modulo $p$ that are smaller than $(p+1)/2$ and $N$ is the set of residues that are at least $(p+1)/2$. So to show the lemma holds, it's enough to show $$|qP \cap N| \equiv \sum_u \lfloor qu/p\rfloor \mod 2,$$ where $u$ ranges over even positive residues modulo $p$.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, the proof in Wikipedia is written quite clearly, in my opinion. But I will try to clarify it further.

Let $U$ be the set of even integers in the range $[1\ldots p-1]$. For each $u\in U$, let $a_u = r\left((-1)^{r(u)}r(u)\right)$.

Each $a_u$ can clearly be seen to be even by considering cases on the parity of $r(u)$.

Each $a_u$ is also clearly distinct, since if $a_t = a_u$ for $t,u\in U$, then we have $(-1)^{r(t)}qt \equiv (-1)^{r(u)}qu$, or dividing by $q$, $t \equiv \pm u$, or using the fact that $t$ and $u$ are even, $t \equiv u$.

Thus, the set of values $\{a_u\}_{u\in U}$ is a rearrangement of $U$. Multiplying together, we have:

$$\prod_{u\in U} a_u \equiv \prod_{u\in U} u.$$

The lemma follows simply by substituting $a_u \equiv (-1)^{r(u)}r(u)$, then substituting $r(u) \equiv qu$, and finally dividing by $\prod_{u\in U} u$.

As for question 2, I believe that the Wikipedia article has a typo. I think it means to say that the lemma follows easily from [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), not from Gauss' lemma.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused about why the following equalities hold (or do some not hold): $q^{(p-1)/2} \equiv (-1)^{(p-1)/2} \equiv (-1)^{\sum_u \lfloor qu\rfloor}.$ And why would the lemma follow easily from Euler's criterion if using Euler's criterion doesn't really simplify the proof of the lemma (the lemma literally uses the criterion in the proof)?

Comment: I think you misread my question; my question wasn't that I didn't understand the proof, but that I didn't understand the addendum.